# Where is the syntax error in my cmd Python?

Tags: python

Since several hours i had some errors in my command:

```
 message = "test."+hostname+"."+service+" "current_state_id "%d\n" % int(time.time())
```

The error is:

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The result will be
message = test.myhost.myservice 2 1467383079

Where is the problem ?

Comment: You're missing `+`s between `" "`, `current_state_id`, and `"%d\n"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two; there is nothing between `current_state_id` and either the space before it or the string after it.

You appear to know about string substitution, as you are using it in that code; you should use it throughout, rather than using a combination of concatenation and substitution.

```
message = "test.%s.%s %s %d\n" % (hostname, service, current_state_id, int(time.time()))
```

or using the new `format` method:

```
message = "test.{}.{} {} {}\n".format(hostname, service, current_state_id, int(time.time()))
```

Comment: Thx it's works, I am a beginner in Python. You have missing a ) at end on your line..

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes:

1)You need a '+' between '" "' and 'current_state_id'.

2)You need a '+' between 'current_state_id' and '"%d\n"'.

This is the correct version:

> message = "test."+hostname+"."+service+" "+current_state_id+"%d\n" % int(time.time())